# cast a column in $filter using Odata v3

Tags: odata

I'm trying to do a cast on a query but it's throwing me a error 500

```
http://source/service/odata.svc?$filter=(cast(Value,'Edm.Int32') eq 1)
```

Where column 'Value' is a Edm.String

Note that i'm using v3 of OData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may get error message like from service:

```
No coercion operator is defined between types 'System.String' and 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]'.
```

Which was thrown by Linq's Expression.Convert, which does try to convert a string value to int value.

This is because numeric types are only supported to be cast to numeric types. (This was explicitly called out in [v4 spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata01/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata01-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc395267162) 5.1.1.4.29 cast).

Please also note that other strong typed languages would also not allow 'CAST' from string to int directly. Thus the following code won't compile:

```
string a = "3";
int b = (int) a;
```

A better solution could be manually casting the const here:

```
http://source/service/odata.svc?$filter=Value eq '1'
```